# Difficulty in proving $i_{\alpha} (\vartheta \wedge \zeta) = i_{\alpha} \vartheta \wedge \zeta + (-1)^k \vartheta \wedge i_{\alpha} \zeta.$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields, exterior-algebra

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. Let $\mathcal \vartheta \in \mathfrak X^k (M)$ be a $k$-vector field and $\alpha \in \Omega^1 (M)$ be a $1$-form on $M.$ Then we define $i_{\alpha} \vartheta \in \mathfrak X^{k-1} (M)$ (the interior product of $\vartheta$ by $\alpha$) as follows $:$ $$i_{\alpha} \vartheta\ (\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_{k-1}) : = \vartheta\ (\alpha, \alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_{k-1})$$ where $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_{k - 1} \in \Omega^1 (M).$

> With this definition in mind we have to show that given $\vartheta \in \mathfrak X^k (M)$ and $\zeta \in \mathfrak X^s (M)$ the following equality holds $:$ $$i_{\alpha} (\vartheta \wedge  \zeta) = i_{\alpha} \vartheta \wedge \zeta + (-1)^k \vartheta \wedge i_{\alpha} \zeta.$$

Which I could not able to prove. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Locally, write $\vartheta = \sum_{i_1<\ldots<i_k} f^{i_1,\ldots,i_k} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}} \wedge \cdots\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}}$. You are left to show the result for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}} \wedge\cdots \wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_k}}$.

Comment: @Didier is it easy? Could you please share the computation?

Comment: Yes, it is. Just try with $i_{\alpha}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\wedge \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$, then with three vectors, and you should see a pattern for the general case.

Comment: So it boils down to prove the result for the wedge product of a vector field and an $n$-vector field.

Comment: I have already done it for the lower degree case but I couldn't able to extend it to for general degrees. Could you please write down a proof of the above fact which I mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: You may use an induction argument, yes. You may also do this directly with the definition of the wedge product. Please, by editing your question, show your computations for two and / or three vectors, as well as an attempt of a generalization, so that we could understand where you fail to generalize.

Comment: I'm sure you can, that's why I gave you hints. No need to be aggressive. If you take a tour on this website you will see that questions not showing efforts (e.g the computations I have asked you to show) are discouraged. Otherwise, this can look like a "do my homework" question, for instance.